# User answer choices displaying the number choice and not what the number is? C++

Tags: c++, menu, cin

I am writing a car dealer program where you ask the user to enter their choice (1. Ford 2.Mustang) But instead of displaying the choices they have chosen in the end, it displays the number choice. Instead of displaying " You have chosen a red 2015 Chevrolet Malibu " or something like that, it displays " You have chosen a 1 1 1 1." Here is the code.

*UPDATE* I have switched to using cases and I still get the same output.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void cars();



int main()

{


int option;
cout << "Hello! Thank you for using CarRight Solutions!\n";
cout << "We have a nice selection of sudans to choose from. Press 1 to start 
your search for the right car. \n\n" << endl;
cout << "1. Cars\n";

    cin >> option;

    if (option == 1)
    {
         cars();
    }


system("pause");
return 0;

}

void cars ()
{
int make, model, year, color;



cout << "\n *****CARS SELECTION***** \n";

cout << "Select a make. \n" << endl;
cout << "1. Chevorlet \n";
cout << "2. Nissan \n";
cout << "3. Honda \n";
cout << "4. Toyota \n";


cin >> make;

switch (make) {
case 1:
    cout << "\n You have selected Chevorlet.\n";
    cout << "Please select a model. \n";
    cout << "1. Malibu \n";
    cout << "2. Impala \n";

    cin >> model;
    switch(model) {
    case 1:
        cout << "\n You have selected Malibu. \n";
        cout << "Please select a year. \n";
        cout << "1. 2017 \n";
        cout << "2. 2018 \n";
        cout << "3. 2019 \n";
    cin >> year;
    switch(year) {
    case 1:
        cout << "\n You have selected 2017. \n";
        cout << "Select a color. \n\n";
        cout << "1. Black \n";
        cout << "2. White \n";
        cout << "6. Blue \n";
    cin >> color;
    switch(color) {
    case 1:
        cout << "\n You have selected Black.\n";
        cout << "A" << color << "," << year << "," << make << "," << model 
    << " will be around $20,000.";
    }
    }
    }}}
```

The output is still:
//A1,1,1,1 will be around $20,000.

Comment: Well you are printing the numeric value of e.g. `make`. You need to *map* it to the string to print.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) (or [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)) is one possibility. Using `switch` statements is another. Arrays of strings a third.

Answer (score 0):

You printing "make" value

```
cout << "\n You have selected" << make
```

But you need to use switch operator like

```
switch(make){
```

case 1:
break;
case 2:
break;
}

Comment: Is it possible to nest cases inside cases? Like would I need a case for every choice of make, model, year, and color?